# Volatile keyword allows access to const structures in UnitTest++

Tags: c++, c, unit-testing, constants, unittest++

I'm using the UnitTest++ framework to implement unit tests on some C code I'm responsible for. The end product is embedded and uses const structures to hold configuration information. Since the target host can modify the configuration asynchronously the members of the structure are all volatile. Some of the structures are also declared as volatile.

I'm getting segmentation faults when I use const_cast to try to modify the structure instances lacking the volatile keyword on the UnitTest Windows 7 host. This makes sense to me. However, if the structure instance was declared with the volatile keyword then the test passes. This does not make sense to me.

Here's a quick code example that shows the problem with gcc on Win7. Switching the define value causes the segfault to appear or not, depending on if the volatile instance of the struct is used or not.

```
typedef struct
{
    volatile int foo;
    volatile int bar;
} TestStruct;

const TestStruct constStruct = { 1, 2};
volatile const TestStruct volatileConstStruct = { 3, 4};

#define SEG_FAULT 0

int main(void)
{
    TestStruct * constPtr = const_cast<TestStruct*>(&constStruct);
    TestStruct * constVolPtr = const_cast<TestStruct*>(&volatileConstStruct);

    #if(SEG_FAULT == 0)
        constVolPtr->foo = 10;
    #else
        constPtr->foo = 20;
    #endif
}
```

Can anyone help me understand why the volatile keyword presents a workaround for the segfault? Also, can anyone suggest a method to allow me to modify the values in the structure for unit test without adding the volatile keyword to all the structure instances?

**EDIT:**

I've just discovered that you can do this in C:

```
#define const
```

Including the effective "const undefine" above in the test fixture allows my target compiler to see the const keyword and correctly place the structures into flash memory. However, the preprocessor on the UnitTest++ compiler strips out the const keyword, so my test fixture is able to modify the struct.

The drawback to this solution is that I cannot add unit tests that verify correct const operation of function calls. However, since removing the const from the struct instances is not an option (need the data to be placed in flash) this appears to be a drawback I will have to live with.

Comment: You are mixing C and C++ on a code level and not only on an interface level, probably a bad idea. These are two different languages. In particular their concepts of what is a constant and what is a `const` qualified object differ.

Comment: I'm using UnitTest++, which requires C++ modules, to test C code. I put all the mixed C/C++ into the same file for the purpose of the example (I can't share the actual code I'm working on). In my environment there is no mixed C/C++.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe a footnote in the standard gives you the answer. (Note that footnotes are not normative.)

In §6.7.3 of the standard draft N1570:

> 132) The implementation may place a const object that is not volatile
>   in a read-only region of storage.

This mean that the structure defined with the `volatile` keyword will be placed in read-write memory, despite the fact that it's defined `const`.

One could argue that the compiler is not allowed to place any of the structures in read-only memory, as they both contains volatile members. I would send in a compiler bug report, if I were you.

> Can anyone help me understand why the volatile keyword presents a
>   workaround for the segfault? Also, can anyone suggest a method to
>   allow me to modify the values in the structure for unit test without
>   adding the volatile keyword to all the structure instances?

You can't. A `const` object is placed in read-only memory, and you will trigger a segfault if you write to it. Either drop the `const` or add `volatile` -- I would strongly recommend dropping `const`.

Comment: My understanding is that const merely prohibits the code from modifying the data directly. Since I'm working on a micro, the const is used to tell the compiler to place the data into flash. It can be modified, but not via direct access.

Answer (score 4):

**Why this strange behavior?**
Modifying a `const` object using `const_cast` is an **Undefined Behavior**.
`const_cast` is used when you have a `const` pointer to an non const object and you want to point your pointer to it.

**Why it works with `volatile`?**
Not sure. However, It is still an Undefined Behavior and you are just lucky that it works.

The problem with Undefined Behavior is that all safe bets are off and the program might show any behavior. It might appear to work or it may not work. may crash or show any weird behavior.
it is best to not write any code exhibiting Undefined Behavior, that saves warranting explanations for such situations.

**How to solve this?**
Don't declare the objects you modify as `const`, Since you intend to modify them during the course of your program/test, they should not be `const`. Currently, You are making a promise to the compiler that your structure objects are immutable(const) but later you break that contract by modifying it. Make this promise only if you can keep it.

Comment: I'd rather say that "`const_cast` is used to obtain a non-const pointer to a const object", as that's the typical use case. (E.g. think `strchr` for C++.)

Comment: C++ has a const overload of `strchr` to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize this was undefined behavior. As mentioned below, I'm working with an embedded processor. The structure is placed into flash with the const keyword. I only have a need to modify it to configure module parameters stored in the struct to setup unit tests. I'll have to figure out another way around it, as I don't want to rely on the undefined behavior of the volatile keyword pushing storage into writable memory.

Comment: Removing the const keyword is probably the best answer for most people approaching a similar issue. However, lindydancer's answer edged out yours as it helped me understand the volatile keyword definition in the spec. Thanks for the help!